# I have some bash scripts. How to store the success or failure of their output into a file?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

So I wanted to know how to write some kind of command in each of the scripts that will output if the script was successful or not and append it to a file. Is it possible?

Comment: You almost certainly should not do that within the script.  Instead, have the caller append to the status file.  Better yet, don't do it at all.  Sage advice from ages past (that is far too often ignored): "succeed quietly, fail loudly".  If you script succeeds, do not produce any output at all.

Comment: Just wanted to have a log file where I can have the status of all the scripts that were run. So can reference it later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `trap` -
https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-trap-command

add this command in your bash file

```
# add these lines at the top of your bash script
echo success > your_output_file
trap 'echo failed > your_output_file' ERR
```

Comment: This is a reasonable approach, but the OP wants multiple scripts to append.  With this approach, only the status of the last script to run will be seen.   Perhaps instead do something like: `trap 'if test $? = 0; then s=success; else s=failure; fi; printf "%s\n" "$s: $$: $0" >> file' 0`

Comment: That is good observation. But I think OP wants to know if script fails at any commands (assuming -e is disabled). In that case ERR would be better than EXIT(0)

Comment: Perhaps trapping ERR is more appropriate (I would agree that no output should be given when the program succeeds), but the OP wants to generate a `success` message.  The key point I'm trying to make is that the exit value is available in the trap on EXIT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard error and standard output to the file. For example

```
echo standard output >> standard_file
echo standard error 2>> standard_error
```